# How to generate a custom cache entry on RTK query without async calls

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I have a micro-frontend architecture and I'd like to understand if it is possible to update the cache of RTK query in a custom way without doing an API Call.

I'm using [Single-SPA](https://single-spa.js.org/) to implement my micro-frontend architecture and from the micro-frontend that act as the orchestrator all the other micro-frontends receive a JSON representing some shared info that must be fetched only once and then shared with the other micro-frontends. I need to write that shared info into the RTK query's cache so I tried the following:

```js
useEffect(() =>{
  apiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getInfo', undefiend, (draft) => Object.assign(draft, info))
},[])
```

This won't work because ([from Github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2247#issuecomment-1100747474))

```
updateQueryData only updates existing data for existing cache entries. It is not meant to add new cache entries.
```

Is what I'm trying to do possibile with RTK query or do I have to dispatch normal action and write normally the data I want on Redux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (RTK 1.8), there is no support for this. There is an open PR, but that still needs some work.